# Populate Backbone.js JSON response into nested collections inside nested collections/models

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, collections, underscore.js

My problem is that I am just starting out with Backbone.js and are having trouble wrapping my head around a complex problem. I want to save a form that have infinite fields, and some of the fields also needs to have infinite options. I'm just worried I might have started at the wrong end with a JSON response, instead of building the models/collections first. Here is a short pseudocode of what I try to achieve.

```
id:
parent: <blockid>
fields: array(
  id:
  title:
  helpertext
  options: array(
    id:
    type:
    value:
  )
)
```

Currently I am working with a faked JSON response from the server, which I built from scratch, and now I want to divide it into models and collections on the client side.

```
//Fake a server response
var JSONresponse = {
    "formid":"1",
    "fields":[
        {
            "fieldid":"1",
            "title":"Empty title",
            "helper":"Helper text",
            "type":"radio",
            "options":[
                {
                    "optionid":"1",
                    "value":"Empty option.."
                },
                {
                    "optionid":"2",
                    "value":"Empty option.."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            // fieldid2
        }
    ]
};
```

The idea is to add fields as I see fit, and then if the field type is radio/checkbox/ul/ol there must also be an "options" array within the field.

My work so far:

```
    var app = {};
    app.Models = {};
    app.Collections = {};
    app.View = {};

    app.Models.Option = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });

    app.Collections.Options = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Models.Option
    });

    app.Models.Field = Backbone.Model.extend({
        options: new app.Collections.Options()
    });

    app.Collections.Fields = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Models.Field
    });

    app.Models.Form = Backbone.Model.extend({
        formid  : "1",
        fields: new app.Collections.Fields(),
        initialize: function() {
        }
    });
```

**How do I split up my JSON response into all these models and collections?**
*(Perhaps I should re-evaluate my approach, and go for something like form.fieldList and form.optionList[fieldListId] instead. If so, how would that look like?)*

Edit: Here is a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/3t8qmnbf/) after many fixes, but I still don't really know how to make the inner options list work.

Comment: One option is to use single model for your JSON response and overridden Backbone's `sync` method for each model/collection associated with some part of JSON. I can't do the full implementation for you since it would be too complex. See for example my [JS tool](https://github.com/hindmost/jslogflush-manager) [where](https://github.com/hindmost/jslogflush-manager/blob/master/manager.js#L71) this approach is used for similar problem as your.

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, I didn't really get all of what I wanted from that link, nor from your explanation. I did go with the single model JSON idea, so I feel I am getting closer to a solution. I might have started in the wrong end though, with a JSON I tried to reproduce. It's better to create what you want from the ground up, not to start with the roof of the house so to speak. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be using [Backbone Relational](http://backbonerelational.org/) or [Backbone Associations](http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations/index.html).

The documentation should be enough to help you get started.

If you don't want to use a library you could override the parse function on the Form model.

```
app.Models.Form = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        fields: new app.Collections.Fields()
    },

    parse: function(response, options) {
        return {
            formid: response.formid,
            fields: new app.Collections.Fields(_.map(response.fields, function(field) {
                if (field.options) {
                    field.options = new app.Collections.Options(field.options);
                }

                return field;
            }))
        };
    }
});
```

Now if you fetch a form from the server, the response will be parsed into an object graph of models and collections.

`form.get('fields')` will return an app.Collections.Fields collection. `form.get('fields').first().get('options')` will return an app.Collections.Options collection, if any options exist.

Also, you could create the form model like this:

```
var form = new app.Models.Form(JSONresponse, {
    parse: true
});
```

This would result in the same object structure.

Comment: I would prefer to do it without additional plugins. Surely it must be possible?

Comment: Thanks, I have stumbled across similar solutions on my quest for an answer, but have yet to test it out. I have faith though, so I marked your answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to handle the case of nested models and collections right in plain Backbone.

Easiest way of handling this will be something like this:

```
   var Option = Nested.Model.extend({
       idAttribute : 'optionid',

       defaults : {
          optionid : Integer
          value : ""
       }
    });

    var Field = Nested.Model.extend({
        idAttribute : 'fieldid',

        defaults : {
          fieldid : Integer,

          title : "",
          helper : "",
          type : "radio",
          options : Option.Collection
        }
    });

    var Form = Nested.Model.extend({
        idAttribute : 'formid',

        defaults : {
          formid: Integer,
          fields: Field.Collection
    });
```

https://github.com/Volicon/backbone.nestedTypes

And that's it. Yep, you'll get direct access to the attributes as free bonus, just `form.fields.first().options.first().value`, without that `get` and `set` garbage.